# DataGrid in SketchFlow Blendability

Tags: datagrid, expression-blend, sketchflow

I am trying to figure out how to show two different states of a datagrid in Blend/SketchFlow on a page. I would like to show the datagrid empty on load of the page and then change it to show results data using databinding with sample data when the Search key is pressed.

I have made two copies of the datagrid - one empty and one with data. I can over lay one with the other based on two states. Is this the best way to show this behavior, or is there some better way to change the Items binding or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with so many things, it depends on your needs and goals.

If this is a mockup/prototype, what you did it probably the simplest/fastest route to your goal. If you need to make it more production ready, you should probably have a single datagrid and change its datacontext or data source.

Comment: Can you change the data source in ExpressionBlend or must it be in code?

Comment: Well, you can write code in Expression Blend :) This is probably best handled in code if you want to change the datacontext of an item.